# how to make http get request to api controller and stores result into some property using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http, asp.net-apicontroller

I am developing angular 2 application, in my current project I implemented the functionality for http get request to my api controller from service class(typescript file).

this is the code I wrote in my service.ts file.

```
   getTodoListApiUrl(): Observable<any>{

    return this.todoListAPIUrl = this._http.get(this._UploadControllerUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <Observable<any>>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('todoListAPIUrl :' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);


}
```

after run the above method, then I am trying to use this.todoListAPIUrl but it always gives value as undefined. sure the above method gives some url from my api controller.

Please tell me how to store result into one filed in typescript file.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Try this, work fine for me

**In your service.ts**

```
private localvarUrl = 'url to data'

getDataFromHttp(): Promise<Class[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.localvarUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Class[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
      console.error('An error occurred', error);
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

**In your component call this method that**

First import your service. After Create a local var to storage data from service. In constructor declare a local var to service, i'm implements OnInit on component, an the result is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

//Services
import { NameService } from './name.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'selector-name',
  templateUrl: 'name.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    local_var: class[] = [] //declare this as your class (you must import them) or any

    constructor(private myService: NameService ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.myService.getDataFromHttp().then(response => this.mis_servicios = response)
    }
 }
```

**On your view HTML**

```
*ngFor="let local of local_var"
```

Comment: Sorry in this line y have an an error `this.myService.getDataFromHttp().then(response => this.mis_servicios = response)`. CHANGE for this `this.myService.getDataFromHttp().then(response => this.local_var = response)`

Comment: I am also doing same thing working fine but I want the the local_var value in service.ts, please tell me how to do that.

Comment: `response => this.local_var = response` this code assingn the `response` value to `local_var`, and you can use in another line with `this` operator like this `this.local_var`

Comment: Question, you need use the `response` on another method inside the service? this is the purpose of your ask?

Comment: when I used above method in that shows some error on toPromise() doesn't exists. even I import the Observable like this  " import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; "

Comment: Why Observable, you need cancel de request? The type Observable is used when you need cancel de request, but Promise is used when you dont need cancel it.
Answer for my last question: you can call other method on service using the Promise callback `.then(response => nameOfMethod(response))` for any Promise, or call the method getData inside of the method in you need the data return of getData like: `methodOnService(){ getDataMethod().then(response => /*Paste your code to process the Data using response like local variable of method*/) }`